# Converting format of hard drive

Tags: disk-format

How to change format of external hard drive from ExFat to HFS+ without losing data? What are limits for maximum size of a file on both formats?

Comment: Have you checked iPartitio? http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php

Comment: @mankoff: Yes, I've tried it after you mentioned. I guess that's what it's made for, but it doesn't work... When changing the format, it doesn't really change content, but just the table, which even makes ex. drive unreadable by OS :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is no way to do that without copying all data to a second disk, formatting the first as HFS+, and copying the data back.

The file size limit under ExFat is about 16 Exabytes, which is higher than the maximum possible volume size. And HFS+ is similarly crazy: 8 Exabytes is the limit. Which means that you should never have to worry about file size again! (The developers of FAT32 probably thought the same though :p)

Next time, please make use of websites [like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+) before posting these sorts of questions.

Comment: I like you're funny :) Honestly, I couldn't find exact answer. I was hoping there is some software like PartitionMagic on Windows for doing the trick (once upon a time I remember). btw I'm almost not closing wiki, i asked the second question just like to mention, probably cuz i didn't understand what are EiBs, but i'll look it up now xD